# azure deploy issue:do not have permission to view this directory or page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, git, azure, azure-web-app-service

I tried to deploy my asp.net mvc web application to  azure. But somehow, I could not using web deploy in vs2015 community, I always receive an error:
Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED. WebApplication6     0.

So I changed to deploy using local git to deploy to azure. I was able to deploy, but when I typed in the url of the web app, I got:You do not have permission to view this directory or page. And I can't access any of the controller I defined in the code. Could any one help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the answer from git hub issues' reply, azure web app doesn't support asp.net 5 anymore.

Answer (score 9):

there are a few thing you can do to trouble shoot

- first find out if your site is deployed.
  go to https://{site name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole, navigate to "D:\home\site\wwwroot", make sure you see the right content is there.
- check if your app deployed properly. If your site is asp.net site, when you do local git push (push your source code), you should see Azure will try to build your code. Check if deployment success. From debug console, go to  https://{your site name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments or from portal you should be able to see your deployment log

if none of the above help you to find out what is wrong, please report your site name here with this instruction https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly

I can help and look into your site.

Comment: For the first one, I am not able to access the page you mentioned. It returns 404  The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. http://webapp6.secureenvironment.p.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole, For the second one ,I am able to see the deployment detail in my portal and It shows deploy success.

Comment: the link should be https://{your site name}.scm.azurewebsites.net, the link you paste doesn`t looks right.

Comment: I found the reason, It doesn't support core app for asp.net 5 any more. Thanks any way.

Comment: Absolute genius! Thanks! My index page was not being copied over to the web server on Azure so of course it will not work. Changed its properties to Content / Copy if Newer and works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue.
Verify following thing-

1. Go to deployed web app on azure portal and then go to App service editor and check required folder structure is available under WWWROOT folder and not WWWROOT->Webapp->bin etc.